# How to align a div to the right?

Tags: html, position, alignment

i want to alignt a image, that is in front of another image, to the right.

In this example the little google image is on the upper left but i want it to be on the upper right:

http://jsfiddle.net/2NYve/

i already tried float: right and align="right" but that doenst work.
As you can see in the example the background is a object with a svg but for this example i simple put a image at this place, i think there should be no different.

```
<div id="divSvgView" dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" style="background-color: #d0d0d0;">
<!--foreground-->
    <div style="float:right;width:30px; height:30px;position: absolute; z-index:5000"><a href="javascript:goToLastNodeDiv()"><img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" /></a></div>
<!--background-->
    <div style="width:100%; position: absolute; z-index:100"><img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    <!--<object type="application/xhtml+xml" id="svgObject" data="" style="width:100%; height:100%;margin:1%;"></object>--></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add (Where 20px is the width of your image)

```
right: 20px;
```

to the image.  That's the only way as far as I know if you use absolute positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/2NYve/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="z-index:10; position: relative; float:right;width:30px; height:30px; z-index:5000">
<a href="javascript:goToLastNodeDiv()"><img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" />
</a></div>

<div style="z-index:1; width:100%; position: absolute; z-index:100">
<img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</div>
```

I added to the div with the chromo logo :

```
z-index:10; position: relative;
```

And to the other one, with the google logo :

```
z-index:1
```

I used the CSS z-index proprety : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Here's the updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2NYve/7/

Comment: i need absolute positioning for my object element. when i use relative positioning the both graphics are not overlayed, they are in a row. But thanks for the z-index hint, i copied it

Answer (score 0):

Set the foreground divs position to 'relative' instead of 'absolute' and add some right margin to place it a little to the right.

```
<div id="divSvgView" dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" style="background-color: #d0d0d0;">
<!--foreground-->
<div style="float:right;width:30px; height:30px;position: relative; z-index:5000;margin-right:10px"><a href="javascript:goToLastNodeDiv()"><img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" /></a></div>
<!--background-->
<div style="width:100%; position: absolute; z-index:100"><img class="mapImage" src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
<!--<object type="application/xhtml+xml" id="svgObject" data="" style="width:100%; height:100%;margin:1%;"></object>--></div>
```

Comment: i need absolute positioning for my object element. when i use relative positioning the both graphics are not overlayed, they are in a row